# org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

Hi I am a new to spring framework. I have done a small example where I tried to validate my input field using spring validation api. This is the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/applicationFormSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertdata( @ModelAttribute("applicationForm") @Valid ApplicationFormBean applicationFormBean, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, BindingResult result,Model model)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {

        return "applicationForm";           
    }
      try {
            Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

          //  applicationFormBean..setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
            applicationFormBean.setSignature(blob);
          //  applicationFormBean.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    applicationFormUserService.insertApplicationData(applicationFormBean);

    return "applicationForm";       

}
```

But when I submit the from with blank value its given me the following error

```
Field error in object 'applicationForm' on field 'applicantName': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.applicationForm.applicantName,NotEmpty.applicantName,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [applicationForm.applicantName,applicantName]; arguments []; default message [applicantName]]; default message [Please enter your nnnn.]

Field error in object 'applicationForm' on field 'applicantName': rejected value []; codes [Size.applicationForm.applicantName,Size.applicantName,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [applicationForm.applicantName,applicantName]; arguments []; default message [applicantName],20,2]; default message [this is worng ]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please change the line in your code, which is shown below.

```
public String insertdata(
    @ModelAttribute("applicationForm") @Valid ApplicationFormBean applicationFormBean,
    BindingResult result,
    Model model,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

As stated in [this Spring MVC tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120115428/http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/):

> The BindingResult must come right after the model object that is validated or else Spring will fail to validate the object and throw an exception.

[This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial#handling-bind-errors) also mentions this problem.

Comment: Great. Been struggling with this for 2 hours.. And I just remember I did the same mistake couple years back.. easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to @ASADUL I solved the problem also with changing the method's signature order.

In my case the `HttpServletRequest request` was next to `@ModelAttribute(FORM_MODEL_KEY) @Valid MemberForm memberForm` which causes the error.

```
@PostMapping(URLS.MEMBER_PROCESSING)
    public String processMemberForm(@ModelAttribute(FORM_MODEL_KEY) @Valid MemberForm memberForm, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
```

I changed to

```
@PostMapping(URLS.MEMBER_PROCESSING)
    public String processMemberForm(@ModelAttribute(FORM_MODEL_KEY) @Valid MemberForm memberForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
```

Note that `HttpServletRequest request` must put next after `BindingResult bindingResult` and `@ModelAttribute(FORM_MODEL_KEY) @Valid MemberForm memberForm, BindingResult bindingResult` must be in this order.